# How to find highest values in multiple columns by grouping the row values using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am working on a dataset that contains three columns; roadType (string), cars and buses (integer values).

```
data = [["A", 5, 6], ["B", 7, 3], ["C", 9, 6], ["B", 2, 8], ["A", 4, 8], ["C", 8, 1], ["B", 1, 0]]
```

Now I want to group rows data on the basis of types in first column and then from these groups, I want to find the highest value from both the columns. 
i.e the expected output value is something like

```
output = [["A", 5, 8], ["B", 7, 8], ["C", 9, 6]]
```

How is it possible using python data analysis library pandas or any other library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
In [31]: d = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['roadType','cars','buses'])

In [32]: d
Out[32]:
  roadType  cars  buses
0        A     5      6
1        B     7      3
2        C     9      6
3        B     2      8
4        A     4      8
5        C     8      1
6        B     1      0

In [33]: d.groupby('roadType').max().reset_index()
Out[33]:
  roadType  cars  buses
0        A     5      8
1        B     7      8
2        C     9      6
```

Comment: I assume this is using pandas?

Comment: @ChrisTomlinson, sure!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code... Forgive me for syntax, I did this one my phone XD.

```
#pre condition, all integers are greater than zero
function findMax(tag, list)
    Max1 = 0
    Max2 = 0

    for item in list:
        if item[0] == tag:
            if item[1] > Max1:
                Max1 = item[1]
            if item[2] > Max2:
                Max2 = item2
    return [tag, Max1, Max2]


outputList = [] #your output List
data = data = [["A", 5, 6], ["B", 7, 3], ["C", 9, 6], ["B", 2, 8], ["A", 4, 8], ["C", 8, 1], ["B", 1, 0]] #your data list
for item in ["A", "B", "C"...]
     outputList.append( findMax(item, data))
```